# change sequence of columns of UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, datatable, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a UltraWinGrid in my form that the user allowed to change the sequence of columns of it.also i have a button in my form that it should send the DataSource of this Grid as a DataTable to a class that generates report.
I have used following code to cast the DataSource to DataTable:

```
(DataTable)UltraGrid1.DataSource
```

but the problem is that the sequence of columns in this new DataTable is not the visible sequence that the user sets...
How can i change the DataSource of UltraWinGrid to what i can see in Grid on screen now??

Comment: Why does the order need to be the same in the DataTable?  The WinGrid should still be able to display the data in the correct order regardless of the order in the DataTable?  If you are finding that this isn't the case, then it is likely that the keys of your columns don't match so the grid may be creating a new band and columns.  You could test with NewBandLoadStyle and/or NewColumnLoadStyle off the DisplayLayout set to false to confirm this.  I would recommend that you verify the the Column names in the DataTable match the keys of the columns in the grid.

Comment: @alhalama,thanks for your reply.but i think i could not describe my problem correctly.my application user can modified the WinGrid (for example select columns that he want to see in grid and also change sequence of them) and then when he press 'Print' button the current WinGrid with current columns and sequence and data should send to a class as a parameter in DataTable type. now what should i do???

Comment: use ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Header.VisiblePosition = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinGrid **Datasource** contains the same object assigned to the property when you display the grid.
 If your user changes order or visibility of the columns via WinGrid interface the underlying Datasource is not affected at all.
 The only solutions (very expensive for large tables) that comes to my mind is the DataTable **Copy()** method to obtain a different table to work on, then, loop through the **grid.DisplayLayout.Band[0].Columns** and use the copied DataTable **Remove()** method for columns that are hidden on the grid (Column.Hidden).
 The tricky part is the order of columns.
DataColumn provides the **SetOrdinal** method to change the columns order, but, I suppose you need to call this method starting from index zero upward. So you need another loop on the grid columns using **Column.Header.VisiblePosition** property.
 But there are other problems now:
 
**First** - The DataTable PrimaryKey must be removed because, if hidden, prevents the Remove() method 
**Second** - The VisiblePosition index could not be consecutive and, if used in SetOrdinal could point to an out of range item.

So let summarize everything in this example code: (requires Collection.Generics and Linq)

```
Dictionary<int, string> gPos = new Dictionary<int,string>();
DataTable dtCopy = (grid.DataSource as DataTable).Copy();
dtCopy.PrimaryKey = null;
foreach(UltraGridColumn gCol in grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns)
{
    if(gCol.Hidden == true)
        dtCopy.Columns.Remove(gCol.Key);
    else
      gPos.Add(gCol.Header.VisiblePosition, gCol.Key);
}
var list = gPos.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();
int realPos = 0;
foreach (var key in list)
{
    dtCopy.Columns[gPos[key]].SetOrdinal(realPos++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the columns and then use the Header.VisiblePosition property to determine the order of the columns.  Once you determine the order you would need to set the appropriate order in your DataTable.